# Liferay - Share Utils class between 2 different portlets

Tags: liferay, share, portlet

I'm developing a Liferay application, consisting on 2 different portlets, an both have to make certain operations in common, so I decided to put that operations in static methods in an external Utils class.

I have to externalize that class to avoid duplicating the same code in both portlets, and I want to have the portlets in different WAR files.

I know I can package the Utils class in a JAR file, but we are still developing and we don't want to regenerate the JAR and restart the Tomcat for every change.

Which is the best option and how can I perform it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the Liferay SDK, you can use the `clients` (recently changed to `shared`) directory to put your common code.

A good example is how [deploy-listener-shared](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins/tree/master/shared/deploy-listener-shared) is used in conjunction with [deploy-listener-hook](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins/tree/master/hooks/deploy-listener-hook).

From what it looks like, all the configuration you need to do is to modify your `build.xml` files that will use the client\shared classes. If you look at [build file](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins/blob/master/hooks/deploy-listener-hook/build.xml) of deploy-listener-hook you can see all you need to add is the.

For the new SDK:

```xml
<property name="import.shared" value="my-utils-shared" />
```

For the older SDK:

```xml
<property name="dependent.clients" value="my-utils-client" />
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: And how can I create a client or shared project with Liferay IDE? Can you give me an example please? Thanks

Comment: Sorry I do not use the Liferay IDE.

Comment: I've looked through the documentation, and it doesn't appear that the IDE supports it.

Answer (score 2):

There is another method that involves building a JAR file but it doesn't require a server restart (on Tomcat at least).

Write a build script for your JAR file so it compiles, builds the JAR and finally copies it to the following location:

```
{tomcat}/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib
```

- Then in your portlet open the "liferay-plugin-package.properties" (in Liferay Developer Studio / Liferay IDE this should open with a nice GUI).
- Then add the name of your JAR to the "portal-dependency-jars" list in this file so in the source it would like (Or just hit the "Add" button in the GUI and select the JARs you want):

  portal-dependency-jars=my-custom-lib.jar,my-other-custom-lib.jar
- Save the file, and redeploy the portlet, and the JAR will be copied across when the portlet is deployed.

I've used this method for custom JARs, and 3rd party JARs that I've needed to use in my portlets.

Answer (score 0):

For the development phase just package the jar file with both applications.

Unless one application depends on the other somehow it is completely ok.

Another solution is to use JRebel tool. It will allow you to redeploy jar in tomcat without restarting.

Answer (score 0):

Also you may have several portlets in one .war. You may just define them both in `portlet.xml`.